How to merge 2 json files using jq (deep merge and concat array)
With jq command, I want to merge multiple json files.
But I have no idea how to achieve below expectation.
thanks in advance
a.json
{
    "key1": {
        "key2": [
            1,
            2
        ]
    },
    "key3": "aaa"
}

b.json
{
    "key1": {
        "key2": [
            3,
            4,
            5
        ]
    },
    "key4": "bbb"
}

expected result
{
    "key1": {
        "key2": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5
        ]
    },
    "key3": "aaa",
    "key4": "bbb"
}


The problem is, that you want to merge like * would, but treat colliding arrays like + would. You could prepare those arrays such that merging with * will eventually work as desired, e.g. by pre-processing the addition, and storing it in the last affected array.
# Use with option `jq -s` so that the inputs are collected into an array
reduce (
  # Find highest ranked arrays
  [paths(arrays) | select(all(.[1:][]; type == "string"))]
  # Group those that would collide
  | group_by(.[1:])[]
) as $group (.;
  # Store the addition into the last of those arrays
  setpath($group[-1]; [getpath($group[])] | add)
)
# Perform the actual merge (for only two inputs, `first * last` would suffice)
| reduce .[1:][] as $next (first; . * $next)

{
  "key1": {
    "key2": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5
    ]
  },
  "key3": "aaa",
  "key4": "bbb"
}

Demo

Alternatively, use another JSON processor that provides such merging techniques. For example, mikefarah/yq implements a *+ operator that "merges objects, but appends arrays". Note that yq is primarily a YAML processor (so the manual is focused around YAML examples) but it can also handle JSON input/output (if not clear from the filename extensions, use the explicit -pj -oj flags).
yq '. *+ load("b.json")' a.json


Here's a "recursive-merge" filter that makes it easy to make modifications according to specific requirements about the handling of nulls and mismatches and so on:
# A "lossless recursive merge" of two JSON objects 
# using `unique` for arrays.
def merge_two_objects($o2):
 . as $o1
 | reduce ($o2|keys_unsorted[]) as $k (.; 

      if ($o1[$k] == null)
      then .[$k] = $o2[$k]

      elif ($o1[$k] | type == "array") and ($o2[$k] | type) == "array"
      then .[$k] |= ( (. + $o2[$k]) | unique )

      elif ($o1[$k] | type == "object") and ($o2[$k] | type) == "object"
      then .[$k] |=  merge_two_objects($o2[$k])

      elif has($k)
      then .[$k] =  [$o1[$k], $o2[$k]]  

      else .[$k] = $o2[$k]
      end );



You'll need to implement your own merge method to resolve how you want to merge arrays.  Something like this:
def deep_merge($val1; $val2):
    [($val1, $val2) | type] as $types |
    if $types == ["object", "object"] then
        # merge objects
        reduce ([($val1, $val2) | keys[]] | unique[]) as $k ({};
            if all($val1, $val2; has($k)) then
                .[$k] = deep_merge($val1[$k]; $val2[$k])
            else
                .[$k] = ($val1[$k] // $val2[$k])
            end
        )
    elif $types == ["array", "array"] then
        # both arrays, concatenate
        $val1 + $val2
    else
        # use default merge
        $val1 * $val2
    end
    ;

Add to your .jq file or inline your filter.
Then to merge your files:
$ jq -n 'deep_merge(input; input)' a.json b.json
{
  "key1": {
    "key2": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5
    ]
  },
  "key3": "aaa",
  "key4": "bbb"
}


If you need to add the option to change how to handle arrays, you could use this version:
# provide filter to resolve arrays
def deep_merge($val1; $val2; resolve_array):
    [($val1, $val2) | type] as $types |
    if $types == ["object", "object"] then
        # merge objects
        reduce ([($val1, $val2) | keys[]] | unique[]) as $k ({};
            if all($val1, $val2; has($k)) then
                .[$k] = deep_merge($val1[$k]; $val2[$k]; resolve_array)
            else
                .[$k] = ($val1[$k] // $val2[$k])
            end
        )
    elif $types == ["array", "array"] then
        # both arrays, resolve
        [$val1, $val2] | resolve_array
    else
        # use default merge
        $val1 * $val2
    end
    ;

# concatenates (adds) arrays by default
def deep_merge($val1; $val2): deep_merge($val1; $val2; add);


jq -s 'reduce .[] as $item ({}; . + ($item | with_entries(if .key == "key1" then .value = (.value + $item.key1) else . end)))' a.json b.json

the result of this command didn't match what I expected. the value of "key2" overwritten by b.json and the result only have [3, 4, 5]
